# postgreSQL function call packet

Tags: postgresql, wireshark, packet-sniffers, function-call

As postgreSQL documentation says about it's packets [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/protocol-message-formats.html) a function call must send a packet with `'F'` identifier to server.

So I defined a simple function and called it with `select` statement and after monitoring my connection port using [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/about.html) I see no `'F'` identified packet, just multiple simple query packets (`'Q'` identified).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a misunderstanding.

A function that is called inside a `SELECT` statement is part of the statement text in a *Query* (identifier `Q`) or a *Parse* (identifier `P`) message.

The part of the documentation you are referring describes the message for the [*fast-path interface*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-fastpath.html). This is a leftover from the time before the frontend-backend protocol had support for prepared statements and was used to execute a simple function call without the overhead of having to parse an SQL statement. It is mostly obsolete now, but still used in a few places like the [*large object API*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html).

If you want to see `F` packets with Wireshark, you have to write C code and use the `PQfn` function.